# Xamarin iOS C# ICMP Pings

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, ping, icmp

Has anyone successfully sent valid ICMP pings through an Xamarin C# iOS app? I've looked into the SimplePing binding port produced by somebody a while back, but it's a bit outdated and not suited for the new unified API. I've read about Reachability and I don't think that's going to work for me since I'm looking for something to give me traditional ICMP ping responses such as latency.

Any one have something that just works without all the headache?

Comment: Reachability tests HTTP connectivity because usually that's what apps are using. I also think that some mobile providers may block ICMP.

Comment: There are a number of OSS ObjC ping libraries that you can create a Xamarin iOS Binding project for, but **make sure** that it supports/uses IPv6 otherwise the Apple Store will reject it ( been there/done that... :-/ )